# Identifying grid cells in the first layer that pass through highlighted property regions across all 3d numpy Z layers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D NumPy array representing porosity values in a subsurface reservoir, consisting of 40 layers with varying porosity distributions. Each layer is divided into a grid of size 50x50, resulting in a porosity array of shape (40, 50, 50) named "porosity_array". I want to identify the grid cells in the first layer that are likely to pass through specific porosity regions across all layers.

To achieve this, I have divided the porosity values into three classes: poor, fair, and good. The class ranges are defined as follows:

```
    poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
    fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
    good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))
```

or we can divide the range into 5 classes as: very poor (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1), poor(0.1, 0.13), fair(0.13, 0.16), good (0.16, 0.19)and very good(0.19, np.max(porosity_array)).

Such selection obviously assumes that we have enough data points in each category so that when proposing the well locations, each class of porosity has representative well locations.

Using a heatmap plot with the 'jet' colormap, the red color indicates high porosity, blue indicates poor porosity, and yellow represents fair porosity. These colors vary for each layer based on the porosity distribution.

I would like to find the grid cells in the first layer falling within the high porosity range (red region) where a vertical red line would predominantly pass through the red regions across all reservoir layers. Similarly, I aim to identify grid cells in the first layer for the low porosity range (blue region) and fair porosity range (yellow region) that align with their respective colors across all layers.
Obviously, one can not penetrate a well throughout all the layers and cross only red color. So the closer to meet this condition is better.
With a smaller sigma value, we would widen ranges of porosity but it comes at a cost of increased randomness and heterogeneity and smaller batches of same color across different colors, therefore less chances of making it through the same color (region) across all the layers. I would assume the winning solution would be the one that captures most of the transition zones available between these classes of porosity in an attempt to increase the chances of conditions survival.
Here's the process I envision for identifying these grid cells:

1. Determine the indices of the grid cells in the first layer falling within the high porosity range (red region) using NumPy's where function.
2. Iterate over the remaining layers (excluding the first layer) and check if the corresponding grid cells at the same indices fall within the high porosity range.
3. Count the number of layers in which the condition is satisfied.
4. Repeat the same process for the low porosity range (blue region) and the fair porosity range (yellow region), adjusting the conditions accordingly.
   By counting the number of layers in which the condition is satisfied, we can identify the grid cells in the first layer that are more likely to pass through the corresponding color regions across all the reservoir layers. The vertical wells must be the same in all the layers and remain in the same grid cells regardless of the layer number. The proposed wells must also be scattered as best as they can and not to be clustered only in one region of the reservoir.

Smoothing the array is done in an attempt to make the provided data as realistic as possible to my own data.

Any suggestions or alternative approaches to efficiently accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated. My code below gives 0 layers for all the three regions!

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

# Step 1: Create an empty 3D NumPy array
    porosity_array = np.zeros((40, 50, 50))

# Step 2: Generate random values within the desired range
    np.random.seed(123)
    porosity_array = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.25, size=(40, 50, 50))

# Step 3: Define the ranges for the three modes
   poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
   fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
   good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))

# Step 4: Assign values within each mode's range
   porosity_array[(porosity_array >= poor_class[0]) & (porosity_array < poor_class[1])] = 0.05  # Poor mode
   porosity_array[(porosity_array >= fair_class[0]) & (porosity_array < fair_class[1])] = 0.12  # Fair mode
   porosity_array[(porosity_array >= good_class[0]) & (porosity_array <= good_class[1])] = 0.2  # Good mode

# Apply Gaussian smoothing to make regions more continuous
   sigma = 1.0  # Lower sigma means wider ranges of porosity, although at a cost of having more randomness and heterogeneity and at a cost of smaller batches of same color across different colors.  Adjust the sigma value for desired smoothing effect
   porosity_array_smoothed = gaussian_filter(porosity_array, sigma=sigma)

# Plotting the heatmap
   plt.imshow(porosity_array_smoothed[0], cmap='jet', origin='lower')
   plt.colorbar(label='Porosity')
   plt.title('Porosity Heatmap (Smoothed)')
   plt.show()



   porosity_array = porosity_array_smoothed.copy()


# Define the porosity ranges

    poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
    fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
    good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))
    
    # Find the indices of grid cells in the first layer that fall within the high porosity range
    red_indices = np.where((porosity_array[0] >= good_class[0]) & (porosity_array[0] < good_class[1]))
    
    # Count the number of layers in which the condition is satisfied
    red_count = 0
    for layer in porosity_array[1:]:
        if np.all(layer[red_indices] >= good_class[0]) and np.all(layer[red_indices] < good_class[1]):
            red_count += 1
    
    # Find the indices of grid cells in the first layer that fall within the low porosity range
    blue_indices = np.where((porosity_array[0] >= poor_class[0]) & (porosity_array[0] < poor_class[1]))
    
    # Count the number of layers in which the condition is satisfied
    blue_count = 0
    for layer in porosity_array[1:]:
        if np.all(layer[blue_indices] >= poor_class[0]) and np.all(layer[blue_indices] < poor_class[1]):
            blue_count += 1
    
    # Find the indices of grid cells in the first layer that fall within the fair porosity range
    yellow_indices = np.where((porosity_array[0] >= fair_class[0]) & (porosity_array[0] < fair_class[1]))
    
    # Count the number of layers in which the condition is satisfied
    yellow_count = 0
    for layer in porosity_array[1:]:
        if np.all(layer[yellow_indices] >= fair_class[0]) and np.all(layer[yellow_indices] < fair_class[1]):
            yellow_count += 1
    
    # Print the results
    print("High Porosity (Red) - First Layer Indices:", red_indices)
    print("Number of Layers with High Porosity (Red):", red_count)
    print("Low Porosity (Blue) - First Layer Indices:", blue_indices)
    print("Number of Layers with Low Porosity (Blue):", blue_count)
    print("Fair Porosity (Yellow) - First Layer Indices:", yellow_indices)
    print("Number of Layers with Fair Porosity (Yellow):", yellow_count)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you essentially looking for locations in the 50x50 grid where it is red all the way through the layers?

Comment: @jared basically i, j locations of where this condition is as closely as met, yes, not only red, but also other two regions (or colors) too (if we divide the porosity range into three classes), similarly.

Comment: So, would an acceptable solution be one where it passes all the way down through any of the porosity levels? It might be helpful if you added a simple 10x10 grid with 5 layers and showed the desired output and explained why it's correct.

Comment: An ideal solution would not be the one that if placed at the top layer at particular i,j index, pass through all classes of porosity. The idea solution would be the one which passes through only one class of porosity. But since the porosity distribution changes in each layer, we can compromise on this idealness by allowing some of flexibility. Final solution then would be let' s say 51 (17 in each class of porosity) or 102 (33 in each class of porosity) potential well candidate i, j positions that can be introduced as the most representative member to each of those three classes of porosity

Comment: What are the i,j locations of those wells? Also, it should be noted that your classes are not necessarily in min, max ordering. With the seed you gave, the poor class is `(0.12, 0.1)` and the good class is `(0.14, 0.13)`. That will affect the inequality evaluation results.

Comment: The i, j locations of those wells are what we are solving for by finding out the i, j of the host grid cells located at the first layer that would as closely as possible meet the conditions described above.  The classes should be defined in order as poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
   fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
   good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))

Comment: But when you redefine the porosity array as the smoothed one, the max and min values change, with the max value being less than 0.14.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the note. I just changed the sigma to 1. The ranges of the porosity classes now should correct. Now, the min is 0.073 and the max is 0.17. and we can have the same classes. Although at a cost of having more randomness and heterogeneity and at a cost of smaller batches of same color across different colors.

Comment: Does my solution answer your question?

Comment: Can you visualize the proposed well locations (i, j) on the porosity heatmap of the first layer for example and color code them according to their well class? The locations of those wells must be fixed regardless the layer number as we go down the layers

Comment: I added a plot that shows the 10 best well locations.

Comment: For the base sigma, how can we color code the well markers (X) so they would correspond to which class of porosity they belong to? Let's say we want to visualize 20 well locations (X) in each class of porosity: meaning 20 in the high class of porosity, 20 in intermediate class of porosity and 20 in low class of porosity?

Comment: At this point you're just asking a new question. If my solution answers your original question then you can accept it by clicking on the gray check  (next to my answer) to turn it into a green check. If you have more questions, you can post a new question.

Comment: Thank you. It did. I will ask a new question

Comment: Before posting a new question, try and solve it first and only ask if you're stuck. Include the code that you try. And don't ask an opinion question, i.e. what's a good way to do visualize something, decide how you want it to look and ask for help doing that.

Comment: Fyi: the new post is here with my new attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638547/identifying-grid-cells-in-the-first-layer-that-pass-through-the-most-same-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm assuming that the paths should be ordered such that the best path has the most red layers, with red gaps filled in by yellow where possible, and blue if no yellow.

To do this, I would count how many red, yellow, and blue layers are at each point in the 50x50 grid. Then, I would sort the results by maximum red, then yellow, then blue.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

porosity_array = np.zeros((40, 50, 50))

np.random.seed(123)
porosity_array = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.25, size=(40, 50, 50))

poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))

red = (porosity_array >= good_class[0]) & (porosity_array < good_class[1])
yellow = (porosity_array >= fair_class[0]) & (porosity_array < fair_class[1])
blue = (porosity_array >= poor_class[0]) & (porosity_array < poor_class[1])

porosity_array[blue] = 0.05  # Poor mode
porosity_array[yellow] = 0.12  # Fair mode
porosity_array[red] = 0.2  # Good mode

sigma = 1.0  # Adjust the sigma value for desired smoothing effect
porosity_array = gaussian_filter(porosity_array, sigma=sigma)


def get_porosity_counts(porosity_array, poor_class, fair_class, good_class):
    red = (porosity_array >= good_class[0]) & (porosity_array < good_class[1])
    yellow = (porosity_array >= fair_class[0]) & (porosity_array < fair_class[1])
    blue = (porosity_array >= poor_class[0]) & (porosity_array < poor_class[1])

    red_counts = np.sum(red, axis=0)
    # ignore locations already counted as red
    yellow[red] = False
    yellow_counts = np.sum(yellow, axis=0)
    # ignore locations already counted as red or yellow
    blue[red | yellow] = False
    blue_counts = np.sum(blue, axis=0)

    return red_counts, yellow_counts, blue_counts


def get_best_wells(red_counts, yellow_counts, blue_counts, n_best=None):
    # sort by largest red count, then yellow, then blue
    # reverse because the sort is from smallest to largest
    best_wells = np.lexsort((blue_counts.ravel(),
                             yellow_counts.ravel(),
                             red_counts.ravel()))[::-1]
    best_wells_indices = np.unravel_index(best_wells, red_counts.shape)
    best_wells_indices = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(best_wells_indices[0],
                                                 best_wells_indices[1])]

    if n_best:
        best_wells_indices = best_wells_indices[:n_best]

    return best_wells_indices


def get_metrics(index, red_counts, yellow_counts, blue_counts):
    red = red_counts[index]
    yellow = yellow_counts[index]
    blue = blue_counts[index]

    return {"red": red, "yellow": yellow, "blue": blue, "index":index}


poor_class = (np.min(porosity_array), 0.1)
fair_class = (0.1, 0.14)
good_class = (0.14, np.max(porosity_array))

red = (porosity_array >= good_class[0]) & (porosity_array < good_class[1])
yellow = (porosity_array >= fair_class[0]) & (porosity_array < fair_class[1])
blue = (porosity_array >= poor_class[0]) & (porosity_array < poor_class[1])

counts = get_porosity_counts(porosity_array, poor_class, fair_class, good_class)
indices = get_best_wells(*counts)
print(get_metrics(indices[0], *counts))  # {'red': 19, 'yellow': 18, 'blue': 3, 'index': (0, 0)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
x = np.arange(porosity_array[0].shape[0])
y = np.arange(porosity_array[0].shape[1])
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, porosity_array[0], cmap="jet")
for i, index in enumerate(get_best_wells(*counts, 10), start=1):
    ax.text(*index, i, ha="center", va="center")
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Here is the result if we change `sigma=2.0`:

[image]